# Apache POI: CellType compare does not work as expected

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.17.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

I try to process String-cells only - but it is not working.

Not sure if this is a bug or if I am using it wrong.

```
    ...
    Cell c = row.getCell (col);
    if (c != null)
    {
        CellType ct = c.getCellTypeEnum ();
        System.out.println (ct + "  vs  " + CellType.STRING);

        if (ct == CellType.STRING);
        {
            System.out.println ("  equal");
        }
    }
    ...
```

Output:

```
STRING  vs  STRING
  equal
BLANK  vs  STRING
  equal
STRING  vs  STRING
  equal
FORMULA  vs  STRING
  equal
```

Why is anything "equal"?

It is the same even if I change == to equals or compareTo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CellType` works as expected, but you have that nasty semicolon (a typo) at the end of this line:

```
if (ct == CellType.STRING);
```

So the block is always executed, regardless of how the condition is evaluated.

Comment: damn I am stupid...

Comment: no worries, such typos happen all the time ;)